# Solving a PDE in seven variables

Tags: differential-equations

I need to solve the following differential equation with the associated boundary conditions.

[image: sss]

I have set up my code as follows:

```
pdesol
= DSolve[(D[K[u, tx, rx, \[Theta]x, ty, ry, \[Theta]y], {tx, 2}]/(rx^2))
        + (4 rx D[K[u, tx, rx, \[Theta]x, ty, ry, \[Theta]y], rx])
        + (rx^4 D[K[u, tx, rx, \[Theta]x, ty, ry, \[Theta]y], {rx, 2}])
        + (D[K[u, tx, rx, \[Theta]x, ty, ry, \[Theta]y], {\[Theta]x,2}]/(rx^4))
        - m^2 K[u, tx, rx, \[Theta]x, ty, ry, \[Theta]y]
        == D[K[u, tx, rx, \[Theta]x, ty, ry, \[Theta]y], u],
    {K[0, tx, rx, \[Theta]x, ty, ry, \[Theta]y]
        == (DiracDelta[tx - ty, rx - ry, \[Theta]x - \[Theta]y])/(r^2), 
     K[Infinity, tx, rx, \[Theta]x, ty, ry, \[Theta]y] == 0, 
     K[0, tx, rc, \[Theta]x, ty, ry, \[Theta]y] == 0, 
     K[u, tx, rx, \[Theta]x, ty, ry, \[Theta]y]
        == K[u, tx, rx, \[Theta]x + 2 Pi, ty, ry, \[Theta]y]}, 
     K[u, tx, rx, \[Theta]x, ty, ry, \[Theta]y],
     {u, tx, rx, \[Theta]x, ty, ry, \[Theta]y}]
```

I get the following error when I try to solve the equation.

```
 DSolve::dsvar: {u,tx,rx,\[Theta]x,ty,ry,\[Theta]y} cannot be used as a variable.
```

How do I solve the differential equation?

Comment: The first error is because the brackets are wrong. Your first equation should be included in the `{}` list. Then there is a followup error `DSolve::litarg` that i'm not sure about yet, might have to do with the way the bounding conditions are specified.

Comment: I think it's then getting upset with the periodic boundary conditions on $\theta_x$, it doesn't complain if that's not there (although it still can't solve it)

Comment: 1. Where's the b.c. for $t_x$? 2. There's only one b.c. for $r_x$?

Comment: there's no need for a boundary condition on $t_x$, because we already have four boundary conditions.

Comment: Why do you think so? _Usually_  for **n**-th order derivative, we need **n** corresponding i.c.s or b.c.s to get a unique solution. (There exist exceptions and subtle cases though. ) Are you refering to something like a textbook or a paper?